# Download file from server plist

Tags: iphone, download, plist

Hi all what i want to do is to download plist from server http:// and i'd like to know how and where it is stored.

Can the iphone compare date from 2 plist files ? ?

thanks to all, if you do not want to post code or explain please link it. !Because i'm really stuck and need help

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're downloading the file, you can use the `Last-Modified` header in the (e.g.) `NSHTTPURLResponse` object to determine if the file has been modified on the server since it was last modified locally. Use the `-compare:` method on two NSDate objects (one parsed from the header, one obtained from the local file system) to determine which is later.